# Synchronize from TFS 2010 server is not working

Tags: tfs, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I'm trying to do a Synchronize/Force on a new dev box and all the XPO's are downloaded from TFS in the repository directory, but I am not see anything new in the AOT. I've restarted the client and the AOS server, no go.

I'm using AX 2009 with a TFS 2010 server. Not the most reliable combo I know...

Thank you.

EDIT: The infolog result of the Synchronize has some errors at the end of it, which is probably why the process is not getting to the point where it imports all the XPOs into the AOT. It's like trying to say a file does not exist but only has the directory part of it (which exists). Anyone know why this is happening and what the message is trying to say ? The `Maps` directory does exist...

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good question. I've added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was two fold. You need to patch the application files (the ones included on the installation DVD) as well. I had only patched the AOS server thinking I'm going to do a  Synch. which will overwrite the AOT anyways. This got rid of the above error, but problems doing the data dictionary synch. started. Finally, I took the production AOT files and copied them into this devbox, now the TFS synch worked. I did a few test (checking in a change from a different devbox and doing a synch on this new devbox, and the changes were picked up).

Long story short, the TFS synch. doesn't seem to work if you are building an environment (RTM) from scratch and try to synch. an RU8 AOT in it.